# Mouseleave function firing unnecessarily in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, mouseleave

Hi all I am working on jquery `mouseleave` event here I have `ckeditor`. I need to show `ckeditor` when I enter the mouse and need to fire when mouse leave here. I have done that.

When entered it's showing (first image) and in `ckeditor` writing some text and when applying some font (second image) it's firing means `ckeditor` will hide (third image). Fonts opening in some separate div I think but I need to fire it once mouse leaves the `ckeditor` div.

Plz check it once here is my code:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btndiv1').hide();

        $('#btndiv').hover(function () {
            $('#btndiv1').show();
        });
        });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.editor.replace('editor1');
    $('#btndiv').mouseleave(function (event) {
        $('#btndiv1').hide("slow");
            alert(1);
            var value = editor.getData();
            alert(value);
            $('#btndiv').append(value);

        });
    });

       </script>
```

here my html code:

```
    <div id="btndiv" style="height:400px;width:800px; border:1px solid ">
    <div id="btndiv1" style="height:auto;width:auto; border: 1px solid  ;">
    <textarea  rows="10"   id="editor1"> </textarea>

        </div>
</div>
```

This is ckeditor when mouse entered

[image]

and this is when selection for apply font

[image: when i selected the styles]

and here it is fired

[image]

but I need to fire it when user completed designing his own text. How can i do this? Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: no i had updated my html div u can check it

Comment: @ Pulkit Mitta this is my ckeditor check it once

Comment: What, you are relying on the user mousing-out of the editor only after he has finished designing!? What about users who choose to park the cursor elsewhere on the screen while typing text? Closure on mouseleave simply isn't appropriate in this case. User must be made to perform a positive action and the most appropriate thing would be to click an "OK" or "Save" button. You might also like to consider a "Cancel" button.

Comment: exactly  you are right mr.Beetroot-Beetroot i had tried with save button it's working but the task need to do on mouseleave function only my task i have to do but on mouseleave function it firing how could to be achieve is there any way

Comment: If this is an exercise to demonstrate your mastery of mouseenter/mouseleave, then you need to choose something other than activating/deactivating an editor. Alternatively, if mouseenter/mouseleave have been adopted in response to an aspect of a design brief, then you must go back to whomever is responsible and tell them politely that they have imposed an unworkable constraint on the design. Good programming starts at the highest level.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor appends floating boxes like the font picker at the very end of the DOM, right before the body closing tag. Therefore it is outside of your div#btndiv1, so this is why it fires the mouseleave event.

The appended div always has the same class "cke_skin_kama" so maybe you can check if we are entiring this div before deciding to hide the editor.

Something like this (not tested) :

```
$('#btndiv').mouseleave(function (event) {
    if (!event.toElement.hasClass('cke_skin_kama')) {
        $('#btndiv1').hide("slow"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: no of use tried but of no use once mouse over it wil shows the ck editor but in case hide not working thnks for my reply @skiplecariboo  any more help

Comment: here u haa given  'cke_skin_kama' how could i append i should call in div or i can directly apply for it\